# Multiplicative combinations of rational functions

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two lists of rational functions in eight variables, say `x[1]` up to `x[8]`. These are generically pretty horrible expressions and my lists have length 64 and 187.

I want to find out which elements of the longer list can be formed as *multiplicative* combinations of elements of the longer list. Obviously for additive combinations this would be reasonably straightforward using matrix methods, but it's less obvious given the fact these things are multiplicative.

I have a vague understanding that some sort of numerical sampling will be useful here, but have never used this type of technique and so would be grateful for guidance!

Generically the expressions are pretty horrible e.g. For instance

```
 -(1/x[5]) x[1] (-x[4] x[5] - x[3] x[4] x[5] - x[4] x[5]^2 - x[3] x[4] x[5]^2 + x[5] x[6] + x[4] x[5] x[6] + x[3] x[4] x[5] x[6] + x[2] x[3] x[4] x[5] x[6] - x[2] x[3] x[4] x[5] x[7] + x[5]^2 x[7] + x[4] x[5]^2 x[7] + x[3] x[4] x[5]^2 x[7] + x[4] x[5] x[8] + x[3] x[4] x[5] x[8] - x[2] x[3] x[4] x[6] x[8])
```

is one element from my longer list (after applying [`Factor`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Factor.html)); I want to test whether this can be formed as a multiplicative combinations of 64 other expressions which generically are the same form or a bit worse.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example?

Comment: Added to post - thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example of the inputs AND outputs you expect? What have you tried? Did you find something similar problem in this site or in the Wolfram documentation?

Comment: The inputs would be the two lists; the output would be the elements of the first list which are indeed expressible as a multiplicative combination of the second. I can't find a similar problem anywhere else; I think looking for multiplicative as opposed to additive combinations is both unusual and makes the problem harder. Currently I've tried simply sampling a bunch of multiplicative combinations e.g. taking only those where the powers in the combination can be {-1,0,1}. This gives some matches but obviously wouldn't be expected to capture everything.